# Asyncore data processing with Python 3

Tags: python, exception, python-3.x, attributeerror

I'm using asynchat and trying to use python3. getting this error:

```
    error: uncaptured python exception, closing channel <irc.IRC connected
    at 0x9a5286c> (<class 'AttributeError'>:'str' object has no attribute 
    'more' [/usr/lib/python3.2/asyncore.py|write|89] [/usr/lib/python3.2
    /asyncore.py|handle_write_event|462] [/usr/lib/python3.2asynchat.py|
    handle_write|194] [/usr/lib/python3.2/asynchat.py|initiate_send|245])
```

My code worked fine with Python 2.6.7.

Suggestions please?

UPDATE: I checked that I'm indeed using python3's asynchat.

```
    ~$ python3
    Python 3.2 (r32:88445, Mar 25 2011, 19:28:28) 
    [GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import asynchat
    >>> asynchat
    <module 'asynchat' from '/usr/lib/python3.2/asynchat.py'>
    >>>
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem is in this snippet? The error says `'str' object has no attribute 'more'`. Check if you're not calling `more` somewhere.

Comment: @Senthess -- Yes, I'm fairly sure the problem is asynchat, since 1) the error message does not mention any of my files; 2) a search for "more" in my files returns nothing relevant (only the word in license blocks).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per http://bugs.python.org/issue12523

> Actually, the error is that in Python 3 you should use bytes objects when transmitting/receiving data over the network, not (unicode) strings.
>   That is, replace '\r\n' with b'\r\n', etc.
>
> Of course, the error message should be made less obscure.

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to be raised in `/usr/lib/python3.2/asynchat.py|initiate_send|245`.

```
def initiate_send(self):
    while self.producer_fifo and self.connected:
        first = self.producer_fifo[0]
        ...
        try:
            data = buffer(first, 0, obs)
        except TypeError:
            data = first.more() <--- here
```

Seems like somebody put a string in `self.producer_fifo` instead of an `asyncchat.simple_producer`, which is the only class in `async*.py` with a `more()` method.